# google map showing error - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to add my custom image in google map but page is not loading giving error saying MissingKeyMapError . i think i have to add authentication key but im unable to add authentication key

**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xyzKey" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>

var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(22.8046, 86.2029);
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  icon:'dustbin3.png'
});


marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:1500px;height:880px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your api key in the script url

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Ref https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key